Why does buffers in Node.js only take memory when they are filled not when they are allocated
Sorry if this question my seem stupid , started learning about buffers and wanted to experiment with them in Node.js , Basically my question is , why doesnt the process doesnt take 5gb when i allocate it without filling since it will be all zeroed out to "0000 0000" , but when i fill the buffer with any value , it pumps up the RAM usage for the process to 5GB
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

// Allocating a buffer with size of 5GB
const buf = Buffer.alloc(5_000_000_000);

setInterval(() => {
  // Just to wait to see whats happening in memory
  // so we can monitor in task manager
  
  // This code doesn't allocate the memory for the process
}, 5000);

import { Buffer } from "buffer";

// Allocating a buffer with size of 5GB
const buf = Buffer.alloc(5_000_000_000);

setInterval(() => {
  // Just to wait to see whats happening in memory
  // so we can monitor in task manager

  // Filling Buffer
  buf.fill(0x22);

  // This code takes 5GB
}, 5000);

shouldnt the first one and the second one takes the same memory space since only the values inside the buffer change ? or am i missing something

How do you determine RAM usage? FWIW, it's not uncommon for operating systems to not commit memory until it's actually accessed but only reserve the address space for it. node could also have similar delay tactics implemented at a higher level.

Using task manager and seeing the exact process RAM usage , when just allocated without filling , means buffer is zeroed , RAM usage is not increasing at all , but when i fill it with values like its showing in my code , RAM usage in task manager for that process is 5Gb , but shouldnt a buffer take 5gb no matter if its zeroed or not ?

The statement in which the buffer is declared does not allocate anything. It's only allocated the first time it is referenced. I think this is because const declarations are "hoisted" before any logic is executed. See link
